# Export report from report viewer to memory stream and then email report

Tags: c#, asp.net, report, reportviewer

I currently have a page which displays a local report (which takes parameters in a report viewer control on my webpage. I have a requirement were the user wants the report to be generated and then emailed via a button click or page load. I have the below code which I have used to try and load the report into a memory stream and then to be emailed. The email part works fine but the pdf doesn't generate. What is the best way to load the pdf and email it since it isn't a physical file as such?

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
        byte[] bytes = client.DownloadData("http://localhost:51997/ReportDetails.aspx?Report1.rdlc&rs%3aFormat=PDF");

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);

        MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage("FromAddress", "ToAddress", "header", "body text");

        SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("RelayServer");
        mailObj.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailObj.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "Reports.pdf"));
        try
        {
            SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked this out by loading the local report into a byte array, writing to a file stream and then loading it into memory stream where I could then email.

```
  Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string filenameExtension;

        byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(
           "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
            out streamids, out warnings);


        string filename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Report2.rdlc");

        using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
        {
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            fs.Close();
        }
```

Load into memory stream:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```

Then send as an attachment:

```
  MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage("From", "To", "header", "body");

        SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("relayServer");
        mailObj.IsBodyHtml = true;

        mailObj.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "report.pdf"));

        try
        {
            SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```